# Tip of my tongue... What official source states that the government would like landlords not to view tenants merely as objects to extract money from?

Tags: england-and-wales, landlord

I was recently reading some legislative document which stated in its preface/abstract/introduction/explanatory note that it envisions an England wherein it would like landlords to take their responsibilities of providing services/value to their tenants seriously, rather than merely viewing their tenants as people that live in their properties from which to extract money.

It might have been a statutory instrument, or a guidance document, or an official "how to guide," or other official `gov.uk` Information page.

My paraphrase was as close to the original phrasing as I'm able to remember, but it definitely referred to "extracting" either "rent" or "money" from tenants as the mentality which they would like landlords not to have.

Does anyone know what document this was?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is about politics, not the law.

Comment: Not necessarily: that would depend heavily on what type of document the phrase appears in: indeed, it is being sought for the purposes of strengthening if not constructing a legal argument.

Comment: Firstly they can be used in judicial proceedings to establish legislative intent in interpreting the laws. Second it has not yet even been established that the document that contains it is not itself a binding piece of legislation. If you can cite the document in question itself and it turns out to be a mere government website with no legal force whatsoever, then this would seem more like an argument to be indulged, but even then, the (surely in scope) question of to what extent it may be cited in judicial proceedings would remain.

Comment: @Trish who writes the laws?  The idea that legislative questions are entirely off topic here is not tenable.  And in the UK, the executive is part of the legislature.

Comment: @Trish, I must agree with Phoog and Joseph P in this matter. This question is not off-topic here. Such a document might or might not be admissible in legal proceedings, there is no knowing until/unless we know what sort of document it is. I urge users to vote to keep this question open.

Comment: Also, this question is more about the text of the laws rather than the motivations of the politicians who wrote them. I'd be surprised if the UK Parliament didn't have a website that listed the text of every single current piece of legislation- I know Australia does.

Comment: And I mean is question about legislating context like the content of policy objective/strategy briefs or pre-legislative public consultations not in scope?

Comment: This sounds like it is likely related to the government's policy on rent reform announced early Aug 2022. [Press release](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/new-deal-for-private-renters-published-today) and [main document](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/a-fairer-private-rented-sector/a-fairer-private-rented-sector). It follows a consultation on reform you can read [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/consultations/a-new-deal-for-renting-resetting-the-balance-of-rights-and-responsibilities-between-landlords-and-tenants/outcome/a-new-deal-for-renting-government-response).

Comment: Yes, indeed this seems like a very strong lead! Will need to log in from a proper laptop with Ctrl-F facilities, but as yet sadly just by scrolling through on the phone screen I cannot see the desired remark. But great pointer, and thank you!